# Android's Mediaplayer not working properly in 2.1 and 2.2?

Tags: android, media-player

I'm using the Mediaplayer (android.media.MediaPlayer) to play mp3-files in an app I'm developing

It works flawlessly in emulators from and above android 2.3. I've also tried it on two devices (2.3 and 3.2) and it works great.

However, in an emulator with 2.1 the audio crackles.

And in an emulator with 2.2 the audio is chopped off before it's finished (plays everything but the last half or whole second).

Is this a know problem for 2.1 and 2.2? And does it only affect the emulator but not the actual devices (which I've not had a chance to test on)?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is happening *because* that the  codecs which the older emulator is using in your case is not decrompressing the audio fast enough (understandable, as it is an emulator). I have worked with MediaPlayer from 2.1,2.2 and learnt that it is best not to rely on an emulator's performance. Go for a real device.

Comment: Have you worked with MediaPlayer on devices w. 2.1/2.2 or on the emulator? Were the devices playing audio appropriately then?

Comment: Devices - yes. Emulators-sometimes. I just used emulators to test if the audio is playable in android. For quality testing, I went for devices.

Comment: Since I won't be able to get a hold of a 2.1 or 2.2 device in the near future I was hoping someone else had tried this out on devices. So just to make sure I've understood this correctly, you have tried Mediaplayer with mp3 on 2.1 and 2.2 devices, and the audio is playing correctly? (sorry if I'm being annoying - just want to be certain)

Answer (score 0):

is there anyway to update the media drivers separately from the rest of the OS?
I updated my X10 Mini Pro from 1.6 to 2.1 and the media player doesn't play any sound. BUT you can see the time counter running fast forward... This is really crazy!   The same with video player, even youtube.  You can see the videos in Fast Fwd, no sound whatsoever.

Any ideas?  Thanks a lot!